# How post data between the backends of 2 different project

Tags: django

Im familiar with using Axios to post data from the frontend to the backend , howevever im having troubles finding materials on posting data from the backend to the backend of another project. What im trying to achieve here is that whenever a user fills in a form in project A , i wish to post the data over to an API endpoint i have created in project B to create an object into project B's database. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an API or views that handle an incoming request for the backend you want to send data to. For example use the [requests package](https://github.com/psf/requests). With this package you can send all kinds of requests to urls you'll need to create for the second backend.